# DRY up a query that only varies its order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I sort my "Posts" differently depending on if a user has clicked "trending", "new", or "top".

```
case params[:sort_type]
when "trending"
  @posts = Post.order("trending_score DESC").limit(30)
when "new"
  @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(30)
when "top"
  @posts = Post.order("total_votes DESC").limit(30)
end
```

There is a lot of repeated code, but I'm not sure how to factor out the contents of the `order`.

Comment: Can you post your view code? I think change the view code could be much better.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be simply to do:

```
CHOSEN_ATTRIBUTES = {'trending' => 'trending_score', 'new' => 'created_at', 'top' => 'total_votes'} #this could be a constant up in the class
chosen_attr = CHOSEN_ATTRIBUTES[params[:sort_type]] 
@posts = Post.order("#{chosen_attr} DESC").limit(30)
```

Another way yet would be to create a scope with parameter for that. In your model:

```
CHOSEN_ATTRIBUTES = {'trending' => 'trending_score', 'new' => 'created_at', 'top' => 'total_votes'}

scope :order_query_by, lambda {|attr| order("#{CHOSEN_ATTRIBUTES[attr]} DESC").limit(30)}
```

Then whenever you want to call depending on the attribute, use:

```
Post.order_query_by 'trending'
```